# How to fix Error:[$rootScope:inprog]?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to resfresh ng-repeat onchange dynamically

```
$scope.$watch('todos', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    $scope.$apply(function(){
       $scope.todos = newVal;
    });
}, true);
```

Probably i wrote bad code and choosed bad way,so maybe i need to rewrite something idk

Comment: You don't need $scope.$apply inside a $watch callback, the callback is already occuring within an angular $digest cycle. `$scope.todos = newVal` is effectively a no-op, the watcher is being called because the value of `$scope.todos` became `newVal` already.

Comment: `ng-repeat` already has a watcher ([as it's part of `$watchCollection`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates)) and changes dynamically, are you sure that this is [what you are looking for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to write this block of code instead:

```
$timeout(() => {
      $scope.todos = newVal;
}, 0);
```

Comment: Instead of $apply or also $watch??

Comment: $scope.$watch('todos', function(newVal, oldVal) {
   $timeout(() => {
      $scope.todos = newVal;
   }, 0);
}, true);

Comment: can you rewrite it without arrow function expressio?